# ph.archive.ubuntu.com is not working

Tags: 16.04, updates, archive

How can I update the version ubuntu if ph.archive.ubuntu is not working? When I tried to enter this in terminal `sudo apt-get update` then I received this error

```
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease              
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:4 http://screenshots.getdeb.net xenial-getdeb InRelease                    
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wiznote-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease        
Err:9 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
  Could not connect to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:d18:0:23::172). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:d18:0:23::172 80]
Err:10 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:d18:0:23::172 80]
Err:11 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:d18:0:23::172 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not connect to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:d18:0:23::172). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:d18:0:23::172 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:d18:0:23::172 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:d18:0:23::172 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: It's down from here as well. You can use`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`, change all instances of `ph.archive.ubuntu.com` to just `archive.ubuntu.com`, then try again.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem. Solution was to

Edit

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

replace all instance of

ph.archive.ubuntu.com

to

archive.ubuntu.com

it is pretty weird why this happens. I guess while setting up your location. Ubuntu tries to find the closest server that they have to your location.

Comment: Thanks men. Helped a lot.